# xy coordinates of each gray pixel in a png image

Tags: image, bash, png

How can I get xy coordinates of each gray color (R==G==B) pixel in a png image using bash?

Comment: you'll need a lot more than `bash`

Comment: just pure curiosity, but could you tell what the hell are you doing?

Comment: I can use imagemagick or netpbm, but dont know how.

Comment: First convert it to RGB (or YUV) then use `hexdump` or `od` to parse the hexdata...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

start with something like:

```
convert image.png txt: | less
```

after, simply grep the result. you really WANT read `man convert` for additional arguments